# React Navigation tab navigation navigate not working on Android (works fine on iOS)

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I'm using React Navigation in my React Native app and I'm trying to change a tab programmatically.

Here is my code:

`navigation.navigate('key of the tab route');`

Whereas in my navigation objects' state (just pasted screenshot in case I might miss a detail if I just like the routes):

[image]

It works great (navigates to the correct tab) in iOS, whereas on Android nothing happens. It does *something* as it returns `true` if I specify a correct route name and `false` if I specify a non-existent one, but nothing happens on screen.

I'm on Android 8.0, React Native 0.59.9, React 16.8.6, React Navigation 3.11.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not receiving any logs?

Comment: @Zun nope, just checked. nothing.

Comment: Can you show me your navigation setup code and the code that uses it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It had nothing to do with React Navigation. I was trying to invoke a navigation tab change by deep linking, and my Android app wasn't configured to keep a single instance of the activity, and it was launching a new instance of the main activity (therefore, a new instance of my whole React Native app as it lives inside a single activity) and messing everything up.

I've added the following code to manifest as an attribute to my activity:

`android:launchMode="singleTop"`

And the problem went away.